# Installing Video Card Driver on Ubuntu in VMware Workstation?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ubuntu-9.10, graphics-card, vmware-workstation

I'm using `VMware® Workstation v7.0.1 build-227600`, I've installed it on my Win7 x64
I've installed `Ubuntu 9.10` on VMware

Whenever I've posted `lspci | grep VGA` in Ubuntu's Terminal the following info has showed : 
`00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter`

Now , I'm gonna use Ubuntu Visual Effect, so I have to install Video Card Driver.
Is it possible to install Video Card Driver in Ubuntu this situation ?

BTW, My video card is NVIDIA GeForce 8600 GT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You should use the VMware driver supplied by the guest toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to connect the Internet through VMWare, Try by going through System > Administration > Hardware Drivers . You'll then see that [Nvidia drivers](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/images/nvidia02.png) are not in use. Check (or tick) the box underneath Enabled to enable the drivers. Wait for the drivers to be installed. Then, click Close once the changes have been applied.

Comment: In `System->Administration->Hardware Drivers` just there are two drivers. http://www.picfront.org/d/7xOV

Comment: yup, you can install one